# How to change Tailwind CSS background color with Svelte, based on a value unpacked in #each?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, svelte, tailwind-ui

I am a beginner in both Svelte and Tailwind and want to avoid an XY-Problem, so here is my goal:

I generate rows of a table with an `#each` loop in Svelte. (6 values per row). I now want to conditionally color the background of this row based on one value (the battery charge).

My idea was to conditionally render different  tags based on this value. Like this:

```
        {#each allLZ as {id, name, mac, status, lastcontact, battery}, i}
        
        {#if battery > 70}
          <tr class="bg-green-50">
        {:else if battery > 40}
          <tr class="bg-yellow-50">
        {:else }
          <tr class="bg-red-50">
        {/if}
```

But this doesn't work as Svelte wants to see the tags closed to be full elements, not piecemeal code, fair enough.

So is there a good way to change tailwind background color based on a value unpacked in `#each`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change approach for that problem. You could use the [`class:name`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name) element directive.

> A class: directive provides a shorter way of toggling a class on an element.

Example

```html
{#each allLZ as {id, name, mac, status, lastcontact, battery}, i}
<tr
  class:bg-red-500={battery < 39}
  class:bg-yellow-500={battery >= 40 && battery < 70}
  class:bg-green-500={ battery >= 70}>

    <td>{name}/{battery}</td>

</tr>
{/each}
```

[repl link](https://svelte.dev/repl/ee8c1aef1d6c47059396728f7aae78ee?version=3.46.4)

Comment: That nearly works (with added quotes after the equals-sign) but only ever colors red or green. The middle condition (with the AND) never triggers. Are you sure this is possible to do?

Comment: Please click on the "repl link" at the bottom, should see the three conditions triggered. Could you eventually paste your `allLZ`? PS. the quotes are not required.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that one. Thanks a lot! My stupid mistake. Tailwind didnt have a yellow-50 apparently. yellow-100 did the trick. !

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend having a function that give you back the background color according to the `batteryValue` like:

```js
let getBatteryColor = (batteryValue) => {
    if (batteryValue > 70) return 'green'
    if (batteryValue > 40) return 'yellow'
    return 'red'
}
```

...and then consume it in the node's class:

```html
<tr class={`bg-${getBatteryColor(batteryValue)}`}>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Have a look at the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d0d465596f054a93b253801ed96128f5?version=3.46.4).

Comment: Easier to unit test relative to @Paolo's answer?